# Can someone please check if I have solved this convergence question correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I got this problem today. Can someone please check my proof and confirm if it is correct or point out the place where it is wrong? I think it is correct, but it is so hard to see what is going on, so I tried something with the triangle inequality and it seemed to work.

I do not need help with showing that the sequence is bounded, just please check if my proof for convergence of $y_n$ is correct.

*Assume that $x_n$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $x_n$ is bounded by an $M \in \mathbb{R}.$ Show also that $y_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+...x_n}{n}$, converges to a.*

**Proof:**(only for the last part)

I have to show that for any $\epsilon$, there is an $N^*$, so that if $N\ge N^*$
, then $|y_N-a|<\epsilon.$

So hence, assume that you are given an $\epsilon$.

Since $x_n$ converges to a. There is an $N'$, so that if $N \ge N'$, then $|x_N-a|<\frac\epsilon2.$

Choose $$N^*=\max\{N',\frac{4MN'}\epsilon\}.$$

Then:

$$|y_N-a|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{x_i}{N}-\frac{Na}{N}\right|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{x_i-a}{N}\right|\le\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{|x_i-a|}{N},$$ this was from the triangle inequality.

Then I split the sum up, i can do this because $N^*\ge N'$.

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{N'} \frac{|x_i-a|}{N}+\sum_{N'+1}^N \frac{|x_i-a|}{N}\\
\le \sum_{1}^{N'} \frac{|x_i|+|a|}{N}+\sum_{N'+1}^N \frac{\epsilon}{2N}$$

And, since $N^*\ge \frac{4MN'}{\epsilon}$
we get

$$\le \sum_{i=1}^{N'}\frac{2*M*\epsilon}{4*M*N'}+\frac{N-N'}{N}\cdot\frac\epsilon2\\
=\frac\epsilon2+\frac{N-N'}{N}\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

And since $\frac{N-N'}{N}\le 1$

we get:

$\le \epsilon$

Is this proof enough, and without or with errors?

Comment: How do you get the upper bound of $|x_i|+|a|$ for $i\in\{1,\cdots,N'\}?$

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz I used that the entire sequence was bounded by a constant M. It was given in the excercise. Then each of these are less then M, and hence less then 2*M.

Comment: And what about $|a|?$

Comment: A part of the excercise was to show that $x_n$ was bounded by a cosntant M. But I omitted that part as I said, because that wasn't too hard. I only needed help with the second part.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz Since $|x_n| \le M$, and $x_n \rightarrow a$, $|a| \le M$.

Comment: Yes, I see. In my opinion your proof is correct.

Comment: Maybe I should also prove that $|a|\le M$, because theoretically there could maybe be a jump in the limit. But I guess if there was a jump you can use a new $\epsilon$-argument, to show that at least one $|x_n|>M$, and this is a contradiction. I am not sure if one can do it without a contradiction proof, that would be very interesting I think.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz Thanks for helping me!

Comment: $|a|=|a-x_n+x_n|\leq |a-x_n|+|x_n|<\epsilon +M$ for any $n\ge N$ is enough to show $|a|\le M$ since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.